# Javascript Prototype method and un-used variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

I am currently building objects via prototype method. This object requires no user built methods and while a factory approach may be better here, I am more comfortable with prototyping.

I am wondering about the `var buf = data._raw;`. What happens to `buf` once the object is returned, does it create a memory leak or is it garbage collected or does something else happen?

```
var Identification = function(data){
  var buf = data._raw;

  this.def = data.def;
  this.master = buf.readUInt8(9);
  this.version = buf.readUInt8(10);
  //more reading from a buffer...
}

module.exports = Identification;
```

I call this function in another module by passing in `data` which consists of 3 properties. `def`, `_raw`, `length`  where `def` is an `int` representation of the object type, `_raw` is a buffer, and `length` is the buffer length.

```
var Identification = require('./Identification');

function main(){
  var identification = new Identification(data);
}

main();
```

Is this bad practice? Am I opening up my code for issues in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: Once the constructor returns `buf` wouldn't be referenced by anything, so i'd expect it to go away.

Comment: "*_raw is a buffer, and length is the buffer length*" - why that? Buffer objects (both [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/byteLength) and [those](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_length)) do have lengths already.

Comment: I set `length` because they sections of a larger buffer. A loop parses it and pulls out the section lengths. Once the sections are dealt with I could drop this attribute but it seemed unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens to `buf` once the object is returned?

It is garbage collected, as nothing does reference the variable/value any more. Your constructor doesn't seem to export closures that would still be able to access `buf`.

> does it create a memory leak?

No, why would it? Standard garbage collection rules apply for constructor functions as well.

Comment: Thank you. Previously while using prototypes I haven't passed data into the construction, they were used as data models with methods and generally started empty.